# Меню для всего сайта в одном файле

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Собственно не хочется писать меню для каждой страницы сайта, и хочется найти оптимальное решение. Более понятное решение - контент отображать через iframe и менять источник скриптом(по клику на пункт меню). Но в сети многие сетуют на данный метод, возможно есть лучший вариант?

Comment: Зависит от структуры вашего сайта и используемых технологий. Одинаковый код (кусок кода) в каждом файле - однозначно дикость и нехорошо. Обычно, используется один общий шаблон для сайта, для всех страниц, внутри которого, в блоке контента, меняется содержимое в зависимоти от страницы. А шапка, футер, подключенные ресурсы и остальной "скелет" страницы остаются постоянными. Реализовать это можно как с помощью шаблонизаторов, так и без них (простыми include в php, к примеру).

Comment: Хотелось бы обойтись html css и js. Если возможно.

Comment: Тогда просто оставьте как есть) Сайт "на html" соответствует технологиям двадцатилетней давности, с которыми отлично коррелирует одинаковый код на каждой странице)

Comment: При использовании php практически ничего не изменится, ничего не нужно будет под корень переписывать. Весь необходимый php-код, в данном случае, сводится к паре строк типа "include 'content.php';"

Comment: @ИванПшеницын, автор вопроса кроме html использует js и ему совершенно не обязательно тащить в проект php, тем более если он не нужен в конкретном проекте. Про шаблонизатор js можно почитать здесь https://learn.javascript.ru/template-lodash. Про iframe забудьте.

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer да, вы правы. Каюсь, про js-шаблонизаторы я не вспомнил. Никогда не использовал. Но насчет "тащить в проект php" - это вы преувеличили. Если проект на хостинге с поддержкой php (большинство хостингов) - "тащить" сводится к переименованию файлов с .html на .php, разделению их на фрагменты шаблона и добавлении по одному include в файле. Мне кажется, вариант с js-шаблонизатором значительно сложнее в реализации. Хотя, может я просто с ними незнаком?

Comment: @ИванПшеницын, может автор поднял VDS и сконфигурировал под проект, хотя по уровню вопроса это точно не так. Просто не хочет использовать php, ну и не надо.

Comment: Ответ "используй php" не лишен смысла, это простая технология, которая используется именно для решения задачи ТС и сводится к <?php include('menu.html'); ?>, как уже написали. Также сомнительно, что можно обойтись одним шаблонизатором. Каким образом вы будете подключать файл шаблона на клиентском js, если js в браузере не поддерживает включение файлов? Собирать сайт? Тут уже зависит от задач ТС, что будет проще.

Answer (score 2):

Можно с помощью того же `gulp` собирать странички, используя, например `jade`

Для этого нужен `node.js`, который использует в своем коде `js`, так что нового языка учить не придется. Но нужно будет разобраться с `node.js`, `gulp`, `jade`)

**Ссылочки**

- [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/)
- [jade](http://jade-lang.com/)
- [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/)

Comment: Мне не нравится совет использовать gulp и jade для новичка, когда задача просто вставить одинаковое меню на всех страницах. В комментариях к вопросу толково посоветовали

Answer (score -2):

Вам нужен шаблонизатор. Код на сервере, который будет брать шаблоны разных частей страницы и собирать в единое целое. Готовый - MODx, но очень легко написать свой.

Обойтись без бэкэнда сохранив грамотность разработки вы не сможете. SSI как самая дырявая серверная технология в счет не идут.

Comment: Эх ты, MODx - шаблонизатор? Что-то новенькое... К тому же, как уже было замечено в комментариях - можно использовать шаблонизаторы и на стороне клиента. Не будьте так категоричны в своем ответе.